# java custom annotation to initialize local variables

Tags: java, annotations

Below code having a lot of variables of type String which need to be initialized to a default value. I want to create custom annotation to initialize them. Sample code is

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target(ElementType.LOCAL_VARIABLE)
@interface Initi{
    public String val() default "str";
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    @Initi
    String test;
    System.out.println(test);
}
```

however, as you can assume, it wont compile. How to achieve this requirement using **annotation**.

Comment: Annotations will not help you setting up any data within your code such as a default value. The annotations are only handled at runtime and you will have to set up manually your variables to the required default value.

Comment: even that i marked the annotation as source ?